# Header size of array in C++ for WDK

Tags: c++, arrays, wdk

Not sure if "header" is the correct term, so please correct me if it isn't.

I'm trying to first allocate a memory, and then use an overloaded (placement) new[] operator to initialize an array of class objects (say, MyClass).

Say, the size of a MyClass object is 0x68, and I want an array of 0x20. So the total size is sizeof(MyClass) * 0x20 = **0xD00**, or so I thought.

Now when I use my overloaded placement new[] operator :

```
pArr = new(pAllocatedMem)MyClass[0x20];
```

The compiler returned size_t to the new[] operator is actually **0xD08**. There is an extra 8 bytes. Looking at the value of that 8 bytes, it's used to store the size of the array (0x20 in this case).

So is there a constant definition of what this header size is, say from WDK, that I can use? Does this size changes depends on compilers or what else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That amount of that extra space, if any, is compiler dependent.  For the languange definition [expr.new, paragraph 15]:

> [It] is a non-negative unspecified value representing array allocation overhead; the result of the new-expression will be offset by this amount from the value returned by operator new[].

It is typically used by  the runtime to know how many objects to destroy when `delete` is eventually called on the array.

Comment: Do you know if this overhead for VC is constantly defined?

Comment: @Andrew: You've got the sources. But I don't think it's official; it might change between releases. After all, portable code can't rely on it anyway, so why would VC benefit from documenting it?

Comment: @MSalters, **Is the overhead guranteed to be the same, at least within the same instance of running my program(driver)?** It seems I can't safely use the new[] placement. Freeing the allocated memory will cause BSOD (I'm on Windows) if that unspecified overhead isn't correctly accounted for. I need to pass a parameter during delete but delete[] can't take additional argument, and de/allocating memory outside of new/delete will get this overhead.

Comment: @Andrew: You can safely use `new[]` **if you play by the rules**. The compiler will apply **the same** correction, but in the opposite direction of course, with `delete[]`. But this merely the same for a matching `new[]` and `delete[]` of a single array, and another array could have another offset applied. This variable offset is why mixing `new[]` and `delete` is Undefined Behavior. A BSOD is unlikely (Win32 applications should not crash the OS) but formally within the realms of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @MSalters, Yeah thanks seems like there is no option for me to use new[] in this  case. I'm on kernel mode so yeah it's BSOD-ing hard.

Comment: @Andrew: kernel mode and using `new[]` ? The Microsoft advice for **C++** in kernel mode can already be summarized as "you better know what you're doing". In particular, the Microsoft runtime for C++ is **not** designed to run in kernel mode, period.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer myself.
Did a little test with a colleague. It appears if the class to be initialized has a defined destructor function, the VS compiler will need that overhead storing the array size. No destructor, no overhead. Is that a bug or a feature?!.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <new>

class Foo
{
public:
    //Foo() {}
    //~Foo() {} // <-- will cause overhead even with user-allocated memory passed to placement new()
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    int n = 0x10;
    size_t size = sizeof(int) * 2 + sizeof(Foo) * n;
    void* p = malloc(size);
    *((int*)p) = 0xaaaaaaaa;
    *(int*)((char*)p + size - sizeof(int)) = 0xbbbbbbbb;
    // Placement new with user-allocated memory
    Foo* pf = new ((char*)p + sizeof(int)) Foo[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        pf[i].a = i;
    }
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```